# When being killed by an object or non-player, does that entity gain the XP I had in diep.io?

Tags: diep.io

If you are killed by a Sentry/Boss/Shape in [arras.io](https://arras.io), it appears on the leaderboard and Sentries and Crashers get visibly bigger.

I would like to know if this is the same in [diep.io](https://diep.io) even though these things do not appear on the leaderboard, because if a player is killed by a shape and then I kill that shape, I would like to know if I get their points or not.

Answer (score 1):

When a shape stole my kill in [diep.io](https://diep.io), I killed the shape and didn't get any XP points other than the regular XP for killing a square. I guess this is only in [arras.io](https://arras.io).